# After shutdown from Ubuntu and start Windows, Wifi just doesn't connect anymore

Tags: dual-boot, 22.04

So, I think my problem is Ubuntu related, every time I'm on Ubuntu, shutdown, and start Windows, my wifi just doesn't connect, it keeps saying "connecting" for a while and give me an error.

I can do 3 things to solve it:

- Restart my WiFi adapter on drivers.
- Start my PC on Windows, shutdown/restart and enter on Windows directly, again.
- Disable fast startup Windows option.

It's a fact that Windows don't shutdown completely, I didn't disable the fast startup option, but the thing is, I never had this issue before, but now I'm using Windows 11 and looks like only now it's happening.

Does anyone know what could possible interfering on my WiFi adapter when I use Ubuntu? Or if it's possible to change something to make Ubuntu don't interfer like that?